# Cannot get rid of extra space in PHP echo

Tags: php, whitespace, trim

I'm trying to output a simple text line in a web page. As an example:

```
Owner, Acme Company
```

I'm using this bit of PHP to output this line:

```
<p class="title">
    <?php echo $title ?: ''; ?>
    <?php echo $company ? ", $company" : ''; ?>
</p>
```

However, when the page is rendered, I get an unwanted space between "Owner" and the comma, like this:

```
Owner , Acme Company
```

Both "Owner" and "Acme Company" are in a database and I've checked that their values are clean of any spaces.

I've even tried `trim()`, like this

```
<p class="title">
    <?php echo trim($title) ?: ''; ?>
    <?php echo $company ? ", $company" : ''; ?>
</p>
```

But that didn't trim the whitespace. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whitespace is the carriage return and indentation of your markup.  You can put the tags together:

```
<p class="title">
    <?php echo $title ?: ''; ?><?php echo $company ? ", $company" : ''; ?>
</p>
```

Which immediately leads to the idea that they should be one server-side tag instead of two, simply concatenating the values:

```
<p class="title">
    <?php echo ($title ?: '') . ($company ? ", $company" : ''); ?>
</p>
```